# Python IF Statement Support

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with dates called "Click Date". Basically, I'm trying to write an IF statement to return IF there is a date or not in the column. IF click date contains any information, then "1" else "0".

[Click Date Column example in Python/Pandas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqut5.png)

Comment: Somehow I understood your question as "Is there any date in the whole column?". If the question is indeed that, then: `(~df["click_dt"].isna()).sum() > 0`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: @Maria I'd do `df["click_dt"].notna().any()`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `notna()` method from pandas [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.notna.html#pandas-notna).

In your case it should look something like this, where the boolean values are saved in a new column called *valid_dates*.

```
import pandas as pd
df['valid_dates'] = pd.notna(df['click_dates'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using numpy, you can return 0 or 1 depending if there's a date in a specific column with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
df["new_col"]=np.where(df["click_date"].isnull(), 0, 1)
```

Comment: I think that's equivalent to `df["click_date"].isnull().astype('int')`